# Allowing form post across subdomains while using anti-forgery token

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I'm wondering if it's possible to allow a form post from a subdomain to the main domain while still using the MVC anti-forgery token. A client has just moved a content section from within their WWW site to a dedicated subdomain. The sites still share the same navigation but the content and URL are unique. The navigation component, which is shared, contains the general site search.

The current site search is via a form post, which utilizes an Anti-Forgery Token. However, when posting from subsite.domain.com to www.domain.com we receive an error that

> The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match

From what I can see the generated tokens for each domain are unique and therefore, I believe they won't match when trying to decrypt on the receiving end.

Typically, I've always done site search like this using a GET with a query string, but they were originally looking to prevent any malicious usage of the site search, I believe.